# Auto deletion of data after the time

Tags: node.js, mongodb

MongoDB is able to control the lifetime of the information?

I need to remove the hash table after the expiration of my time.

**Structure**:

```
db.cache

{
    key: int,
    value: hash-table,
    stamp: Date(); // time to create data
}
```

Need to remove the key `key` after some time.

I tried this:

`db.cache.ensureIndex( { "key": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3 } ) // update time 3 sec`

But it does not work. Tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to expire documents, you should index a field that hold values of BSON date type or an array of BSON date-typed objects.

You can change your ensureIndex query as follows :

```
db.cache.ensureIndex({ "stamp": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3 })
```

For more information, read [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) document.